# Synchronization bidirectional with pt-table-sync

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I'm trying to bidirectionally synchronize two databases (one local and one remote) using the command:

```
pt-table-sync --print --bidirectional --conflict-column * 
--conflict-comparison newest --databases my_db 
h=localhost,u=root,p=my_pass, h=ip_remote_server
```

Displays the error:

```
DBI connect(';host=Aplicaciones;mysql_read_default_group=client','',...) 
failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'Aplicaciones' (2) at 
/usr/bin/pt-table-sync line 2208
```

They have both the same username and password for the database as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854239/1116802)?

I do not understand properly the [documentation](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html#).

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I succeeded.

**1.-** The username, password and the name of the database must be the same.

**2.-** Give permission to the user to connect remotely to another server. You can follow [this guide](http://www.openredes.com/2011/08/04/evitar-error-1130-hy000-host-x-x-x-x-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-configurar-acceso-remoto-al-servidor-mysql/).

**3.-** Run the following scripts:

Server Local:

```
GRANT SELECT, REPLICATION CLIENT, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'your_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

Server Remote:

```
GRANT SELECT, REPLICATION CLIENT, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, PROCESS ON *.* TO 'your_user'@'your_real_ip_local' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

**4.-** Case for testing: Table 'color'

Server Local:

```
+----------+--------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| id_color | name   | status | deleted | date_register       |
+----------+--------+--------+---------+---------------------+
|        1 | Negro  |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        2 | Blue   |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        3 | Gray   |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        4 | Silver |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        5 | Tan    |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        6 | White  |      1 |       0 | 2012-04-05 14:14:37 |
+----------+--------+--------+---------+---------------------+
```

Server Remote:

```
+----------+----------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| id_color | name     | status | deleted | date_register       |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+---------------------+
|        1 | Black    |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        2 | Blue     |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        3 | Gray     |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        4 | Silver   |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        5 | Tan      |      1 |       0 | 2012-01-26 00:35:19 |
|        6 | White    |      1 |       0 | 2012-04-05 14:14:37 |
|        7 | Amarillo |      1 |       0 | 2013-10-19 01:25:08 |
+----------+----------+--------+---------+---------------------+
```

**5.-** Running the command:

```
$ pt-table-sync --print --bidirectional --conflict-column 'name' --conflict-comparison newest h=ip_your_server_remote,u=your_user,p=your_password,D=your_db,t=color h=localhost
```

**6.-** Results:

```
/*ip_your_server_remote*/ UPDATE `your_db`.`color` SET `name`='Negro', `status`='1', `deleted`='0', `date_register`='2012-01-26 00:35:19' WHERE `id_color`='1' LIMIT 1;
/*localhost*/ INSERT INTO `your_db`.`color`(`id_color`, `name`, `status`, `deleted`, `date_register`) VALUES ('7', 'Amarillo', '1', '0', '2013-10-19 01:25:08');
```

To execute directly the result, you can change the option `--print` by the option `--execute`.

I hope it's useful for someone.